# multiple relational (comparison) operators: why isn't `x < y > z` a valid syntax?

Tags: r

This might be a dumb question, but I'm interested in why `R` doesn't allow multiple relational  operators in a statement, say,

```
2 < 5 > 3
```

R returns

> Error: unexpected '>' in "2 < 5 >"

instead of `TRUE`.

Comment: you need to use AND `&` or OR `|` operators.. Or use `%between%` or `between()` or `%in%` or ...

Comment: Try `2 < 5 & 5 > 3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm interested in why R doesn't allow multiple relational operators in a statement.

Could you name an example programming / scientific language that allows `0 < 5 > 3`?

Suppose this syntax is legitimate, then what is the default rule for it? Which of the following is correct?

```
(0 < 5) > 3  =>  TRUE > 3  =>  1 > 3  =>  FALSE
0 < (5 > 3)  =>  0 < TRUE  =>  0 < 1  =>  TRUE
```

I think you know that the legitimate syntax is `(0 < 5) && (5 > 3)`.

---

Note that the original question title "multiple logical operators" is imprecise. `">"` is a relational operator not a logical one. Using multiple logical operators in a statement is not a problem, say

```
FALSE && FALSE || TRUE
!FALSE || TRUE
```

However, be aware that (mixed) logical operations are not associative:

```
(FALSE && FALSE) || TRUE  =>  FALSE || TRUE  =>  TRUE
FALSE && (FALSE || TRUE)  =>  FALSE && TRUE  =>  FALSE

(!FALSE) || TRUE  =>  TRUE || TRUE  =>  TRUE
!(FALSE || TRUE)  ==>  !TRUE  => FALSE
```